# Appropriate max_length for atom id field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, atom-feed

I am using atom feeds within a Django application, and was planning on using a [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) to represent the id field of an entry. Given that `max_length` is required, what would be an appropriate length?

Comment: why do you want to use charfield for id ? Should it not be AutoField ?

Comment: Not for the database id. For the [Atom](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287) feed id.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the standard to say how long the ID can be, so whatever value you choose, there's always a chance you might encounter a longer one. What's the longest one you've ever encountered yourself?

Comment: I would imagine it is the same max length for an IRI (Internationalized Resource Identifier) - which is about 4kb.

Comment: @karthikr Strange. I had a quick look through the IRI spec, and couldn't find any reference to maximum lengths.

Comment: Looks like the IETF have had an [open ticket](http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/iri/trac/ticket/47) on this for three years. :-)

Comment: Hmm, so perhaps a TextField would be a better way to go potentially

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers for a related question you may wish to adopt the answer from.